# Jest coverage in redux reducer - object destruction not covered

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, jestjs

I have the following issue with Jest: 
I have this reducer:

```
[REMOVE_FILTER]: (state: FiltersState, action: Action<string>): FiltersState => {
    const { [action.payload!]: deleted, ...activeFilters } = state.activeFilters;
    return { ...state, activeFilters, createFilterSelection: undefined, filterCreateOpen: false };
}
```

When I am trying to test it, it says that I do not have coverage for

```
...activeFilters } = state.activeFilters;
```

Here is my test:

```
test(REMOVE_FILTER, () => {
    const action: IAction<string> = {
        type: REMOVE_FILTER,
        payload: "subprovider"
    };

    expect(
        testReducer({ reducer, state, action })
    ).toEqual({
        ...state,
        activeFilters: { name: null, branded: null },
        createFilterSelection: undefined,
        filterCreateOpen: false
    });
});
```

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong?

I am using:

1. Jest 23.6.0
2. Typescript 3.4.0
3. Redux 4.0.0
4. React-Redux: 6.0.0
5. Redux Actions: 2.6.1

Thank you!

P.S: Here is the Jest config:

```
{
  "coverageThreshold": {
    "global": {
      "branches": 100,
      "functions": 100,
      "lines": 100,
      "statements": 100
    }
  },
  "globals": {
    "window": true,
    "document": true
  },
  "transform": {
    ".(ts|tsx)": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
  },
  "testRegex": "(/__test__/.*)\\.test\\.(ts|tsx)$",
  "notify": true,
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "**/*.{ts,tsx}"
  ],
  "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
    "(/__e2e__/.*)",
    "(/__specs__/.*)",
    "(/__test__/.*)",
    "(/interfaces/.*)",
    "(index.ts)",
    "(src/server/app.ts)",
    "(src/server/config.ts)",
    "(/mock/.*)",
    "(data/mock.ts)",
    "(automapperConfiguration.ts)",
    "(src/app/store/store.ts)",
    "(src/app/containers/brand-configuration/.*)"
  ],
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js",
    "json"
  ],
  "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/jestSetup.js",
  "testURL": "http://localhost/"
}
```

The above TS code gets transpilled to:

```
    [REMOVE_FILTER]: (state, action) => {
        const _a = state.activeFilters, _b = action.payload, deleted = _a[_b], activeFilters = __rest(_a, [typeof _b === "symbol" ? _b : _b + ""]);
        return Object.assign({}, state, { activeFilters, createFilterSelection: undefined, filterCreateOpen: false });
    }
```

Comment: Assuming that you are using `babel` to transpile your files with this ES6 syntax. Can you add your babel and jest configuration?

Comment: Hi, I am not using Babel, but the Typescript compiler. jest config added in the post